# List of Open Source projects that aid Android app development

Tags: android, open-source

A lot of open source libraries that aid in Android application development have sprung up with time. IMO looking at source code of good projects helps learn the system better, faster and not to mention reduces development time. Is there a recommended list of such projects or if not, can we build such a list? I think it will really be useful to other developers.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just published a menu component: https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu It is like the menu in Path's android app.

Comment: This open source GitHub project (MAHAndroidUpdater)is providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 19, accepted):

source.android.com
Examples in SDK

- http://code.google.com/p/shelves/
- http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/
- http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/
- http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

I'd also recommend search public repos such as code.google.com, github, bitbucket for keyword android.

Answer (score 11):

I'll offer up my [CommonsWare Android Components](http://commonsware.com/cwac) (CWAC).

Answer (score 8):

Try Android-Query.

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

It's designed to make Android coding simpler.

Answer (score 3):

http://android.wordpress.org/development/

Answer (score 3):

A more up-to-date list would include, for sure :

- [Roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) (for dependency injection)
- [Actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (for a backward compatible action bar)
- [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) (to get backward compatible holo theme)
- [Spring Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android/) (to get a robust rest client)

Answer (score 2):

I have heard of [droid-fu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu)

Comment: The project merged into [ignition](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition).