# Open source Blackberry Projects which help development

Tags: blackberry, open-source

You guys know any open source Blackberry applications. IMO looking at source code of good projects helps learn the system better, faster and not to mention reduces development time. Is there a recommended list of such projects or if not, can we build such a list? I think it will really be useful to other developers.

Comment: try this link https://github.com/blackberry

Comment: I saw your message on Quora. There are not many open source projects because platform specifics. But there are some. I will collect links shortly

Comment: And BTW did you mention BB java platform, bb 10 or both? And what language/technology are you targeting - java/bb, c++, webworks/javascript, flash/flex, java/android?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention about the platform. I intend to develop using the Java native BB SDK. Will be happy if you could share your links. Thanks a lot Eugen.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Request you to share some links. I find your netherland forum helpful too.

Comment: If you want samples, check out blackberry.github.com/samples.  This is a dynamic catalog and it currently has >280 samples.

Comment: Regarding frameworks, it will vary by platform, but you can get started with blackberry.github.com or go to the repos directly at blackberry.github.com/repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My apologize for delay in answer. Here are links for useful Java BB apps, libraries and code:

1. [Wordpress for BB](http://blackberry.wordpress.org/development/)
2. [LogicMail](http://www.logicmail.org/) - alternate mail client
3. [Facebook SDK for BB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/) - FB SDK not from RIM nor FB
4. [Wireless music sync app](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbwifimusicsync/?source=directory)
5. [BB Tracker](http://bbtracker.org/) - quite old one
6. [BB tools](http://www.marky.com/files/bb/BBTools-Source.zip) - also quite old one

I'm not saying that code from there is standard (For me the **LogicMail** is most acceptable) but there are plenty of useful code about networking, storage, gps and ui. As well please take in attention advanced UI samples from RIM mentioned by @Nate

Answer (score 3):

I only have time to post one link here, but this is one I would definitely recommend for all beginners, because it helps understand UI development, which (in my opinion) is definitely more difficult to learn on BlackBerry versus other mobile platforms (especially Android or iOS).

[See information about it on BlackBerry's site here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)

or the [github repository here](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI)

If you're using the legacy BlackBerry Java APIs (OS <= 7), you will certainly wind up subclassing the built-in RIM UI classes, to add functionality of your own.  There's a good chance that many of the things you want to do are already done, or at least started, in this **Advanced UI** project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nate. However these are just another tutorials from Blackberry. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840231/open-source-examples-of-well-designed-android-applications
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036213/list-of-open-source-projects-that-aid-android-app-development

Comment: As Nate indicates, that repository and document provide a good set of UI functionality for the java-based BlackBerry devices.  There is much more information for the new BlackBerry-10 devices at blackberry.github.com, covering the HTML5, native (Qt, Cascades, and ports) and AIR.